# Clear Session variable data in Session class

Tags: c#, session-variables

In my project session class I am using session the variable `Sessiondata.RecentAssetList` to store all recents access Id's. I want to get only last 5 records from session, or once session variable count gets 5 `Sessiondata.RecentAssetList` first stored Id value need to remove and start adding recent value so now session count will be 5 only.

How can achieve this?

Comment: Didn't this same question get asked yesterday..???

Comment: No I want to clear session variables and add most recent 5 accessed records to my session

Answer (score 0):

That's called a recently used list.AFAIK there isn't one in the BCL, so you'll have to implent one yourself. You could base it on a list, append first five, then delete the first when further element are added.

The implementation on the left on slide 17 here: http://www.accu-usa.org/Slides/with_economy_and_elegance.pdf shows more or less how to do it. Just add the 5 element constraint.